# how to scroll the screen Listview builder inside column

Tags: flutter, listview

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 1,
        backgroundColor: appBarColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('News'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          news.length < 2
              ? ImageSlideshow(
                  children: [NewsSlideWidget0(news: news)],
                )
              : ImageSlideshow(
                  children: [
                    NewsSlideWidget0(news: news),
                    NewsSlideWidget1(news: news)
                  ],
                ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ListTile(
              // selectedTileColor: Colors.white,

              title: Text(news_screen_title, style: news_screen_title_tstyle),
              subtitle: Text(news_screen_subtitle),
            ),
          ),
          news.isEmpty
              ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
              : Expanded(
                  child: LazyLoadScrollView(
                    onEndOfPage: () => loadNextPage(),
                    scrollOffset: 10,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: news.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => NewsInnerScreen(
                                    title: news[i].title,
                                    date: news[i].date,
                                    image: news[i].images[0],
                                    content: parse(news[i].content).body!.text,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              
                              child: ListTile(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                title: Text(
                                  news[i].title,
                                  
                                ),
                                subtitle: Column(
                                  
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      parse(news[i].content).body!.text,
                                      
                                      style:
                                        
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      news[i].date,
                                     
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                trailing: ConstrainedBox(
                                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                    minWidth: 100,
                                    minHeight: 300,
                                    maxWidth: 104,
                                    maxHeight: 300,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                   
                                    child: Image(
                                     
                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                        news[i].images[0],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

my screen is like this I want this column to scrollable I tried singlechildscrollview and listview those did not work for me and I use a plugin for pagination and I use more widgets also and I extracted that and u I use image slide show packages for carousel so how can I do that I am new to flutter please let me know

Answer (score 0):

All list builder in Flutter have property called "shrinkWrap"
Just turn it to "true"

Comment: i want my entire screen scrollable according to my code

Comment: You must change physics property to "const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),"
This available in list widgets
Your widgets in SingleChildScrollView must be have physics property to change scroll able